# Custom Objects with Apache Pulsar and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-pulsar, spring-pulsar

I'm using Apache Pulsar for the first time but finding it hard to publish and listen to custom objects. I have defined schemas as directed by [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_schema) reference pages but for some reason it’s not working.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuickbooksApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(QuickbooksApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Data
  @Builder
  @ToString
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public static class SomeClass {
    private String someVariable;
  }

  @Bean
  ApplicationRunner runner(PulsarTemplate<SomeClass> pulsarTemplate) {
    pulsarTemplate.setSchema(JSONSchema.of(SomeClass.class));
    SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.builder().someVariable("Hello World!!!").build();
    return (args) -> pulsarTemplate.send("hello-pulsar", someClass);
  }

  @PulsarListener(
      subscriptionName = "hello-pulsar-subscription",
      topics = "hello-pulsar",
      schemaType = SchemaType.AUTO_CONSUME)
  void listen(SomeClass message) {
    System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
  }
}
```

When I run this I simply get two errors,

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.pulsar.common.util.netty.DnsResolverUtil cannot access class sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net to unnamed module @544ff9ef
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392) ~[na:an]

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Schema.getSchemaInfo()" because the return value of "org.springframework.pulsar.listener.PulsarContainerProperties.getSchema()" is null

When I consume it as string though, everything works.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The 1st error is due to Java17 strong encapsulation of internals by default. To get around this you end up having to `add-opens` in all the places you are launching. [Here is an example](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-pulsar/blob/7ee744bcfce2c33245c3795079b60d120be7eaca/spring-pulsar-sample-apps/sample-app1/build.gradle#L19) that sets it for the `bootRun` when using the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin to launch the app. This is an annoyance, but not the cause of the final NPE.

The actual cause is that `SchemaType.AUTO_CONSUME` is not supported in `@PulsarListener`. Set it to `SchemaType.JSON`. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_specify_schema_information) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `SchemaType.JSON` and have your SomeClass Object follow the required conventions for json serialization/deserialization.

You can include the SchemaType in your consumer as below:

```
@PulsarListener(subscriptionName = "hello-pulsar-subscription", topics = "hello-pulsar", schemaType = SchemaType.JSON)
public void consumeMessage(SomeClass message) {
    // further processing of your message
}
```

for Complete post on similar topic check the [Apache Pulsar and Spring Boot](https://www.wranto.com/2023/06/apache-pulsar-and-spring-boot-wranto.html) post.